# Is there an R function that can comb through a .csv file and move selected files listed on that spreadsheet to a new folder?

Tags: r, excel, csv, jpeg, move

I have used the package camtrapR to rename thousands of trail camera photos. The output .csv file has a column with the file path to the renamed photos and the new names they were given by camtrapR. Following the use of camtrapR one of my team members has added a new column to the .csv file for the type of species in the photo. They then went through all of the photos and put a value in that column based on what they saw in the picture (example: squirrel).

I would like to use the package MLWIC to train a model with the photos that have already been characterized by my team member. My goal is to save all of the characterized pictures in folders specific to each photographed species. I've started by going through the .csv file, finding the files that were characterized as squirrels, and then going through and moving each of those to my new squirrel folder. Then doing the same with foxes, etc. This is very time intensive, and I know there must be an R script that can expedite this process. I'm looking for something that will allow me to specify "squirrel" and then R will find all instances of "squirrel" in the species column of the .csv file, and then follow the file path on that same line of the spreadsheet to find the photo, and move it to a new designated folder.

Based on some research online I have found that file.copy can be used to create a new folder, copy, and move photos into it from the original location. The problem with this is that it will move all photos from the original folder to the new folder.

```
cams = read.csv("siteAcameras.csv", header=true)

dir.create(squirrel)

photos <- list.files(pattern='*.jpg')

file.copy(photos,
      to = "squirrel", recursive = TRUE,
      overwrite = TRUE, copy.mode = TRUE, copy.date = FALSE)
```

I expect that there is R script that can comb a .csv file and use file.copy to only move files from selected lines of the .csv based on a column value. Searching the internet has so far proven fruitless.

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tRHnl.png): [The .cvs file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tRHnl.png)

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wKNwf.png): [The manual file moving process](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wKNwf.png)

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry, I just thought of the answer myself. The MLWIC package uses a .csv called data_info.csv to specify the file names of all photos being ran through in one column and a numerical species identifier in the second column. I can simply cut and past the .csv file I'm working with into that and it should work fine.

This is why we think before we type.